# Is there any way to increase the display speed of the SimpleModal dialog in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I am using the `SimpleModal` plug-in in jQuery.

When I use the action event, the modal dialog appears slowly.

Is there any way to increase the speed of the modal dialog, so it appears quicker?

Comment: Because Of I mentioned Response time ,Mork Given Alternate Answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the onOpen callback described at the modal homepage:

```
data.modal({onOpen: function (dialog) {
  dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
    dialog.container.slideDown('slow', function () {
      dialog.data.fadeIn('slow');
    });
  });
}});
```

Try using different values for the fadeIn function instead of slow if this changes something.

Comment: I need Speedup the PopUpMenu Mork,But ur solution is For making slow.Since Appearing Popup menu after click should happen suddenly.not by slow

Comment: As i said, use different values for the pace. the opposite of is slow should be fast.

Answer (score 0):

I had users complaining about speed.  Even fadeIn fast can be a little slow as well for the modal (depending on who's using it).  One thing I found that seems to help is just to call the show function with a low number instead...

```
$(content).modal({onOpen: function (dialog) {
    dialog.overlay.show(10, function () {
        dialog.container.show(10, function () {
            dialog.data.show(10);
        });
    });
});
```